# Appveyor – How to switch off deploy if there is not git tag

Tags: continuous-integration, appveyor

I have this in my config and I want switch off deploy when git tag is missing

`build: off
test: on
deploy: on`

How can I do than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about conditional deployment and specifically deployment on tag [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/#deploy-on-tag-github-and-gitlab-only).

Comment: Yes thank you, I saw this, but it didn't help me. For deploy I have scripts running inside `deploy_script` and `after_deploy`. 


And I mistake `deploy: off` not disable executing it.


How can I use your info for `deploy_script`.

Comment: Please check [this](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/2042) issue. Workaround is in [this](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/2042#issuecomment-359051657) post (basically use `APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG` [environment variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/)).